# Create an order with Coupon_lines in woocomerce rest api

Tags: android, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create an order with coupon in an android app through woocommerce rest api. I can get coupon information, also I can create the order, but discount does not apply. order creates with it's original price!

without coupons every thing works fine.

here is the order response from API (I removed some useless data from it)

```
{
  "id": 23136,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "number": "23136",
  "order_key": "wc_order_5aasdad3128608",
  "created_via": "rest-api",
  "version": "3.2.6",
  "status": "pending",
  "currency": "USD",
  "date_created": "2018-03-18T17:14:17",
  "date_created_gmt": "2018-03-18T13:44:17",
  "date_modified": "2018-03-18T17:14:17",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2018-03-18T13:44:17",
  "discount_total": "0",
  "discount_tax": "0",
  "shipping_total": "0",
  "shipping_tax": "0",
  "cart_tax": "0",
  "total": "67500",
  "total_tax": "0",
  "prices_include_tax": false,
  "customer_id": 0,
  "customer_ip_address": "",
  "customer_user_agent": "",
  "customer_note": "",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "...",
    "last_name": "...",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "",
    "email": "...",
    "phone": "..."
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": ""
  },
  "payment_method": "...",
  "payment_method_title": "...",
  "transaction_id": "",
  "date_paid": null,
  "date_paid_gmt": null,
  "date_completed": null,
  "date_completed_gmt": null,
  "cart_hash": "",
  "meta_data": [],
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 1792,
      "name": "...",
      "product_id": 22359,
      "variation_id": 22361,
      "quantity": 1,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "67500",
      "subtotal_tax": "0",
      "total": "67500",
      "total_tax": "0",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 19325,
          "key": "...",
          "value": "..."
        },
        {
          "id": 19326,
          "key": "...",
          "value": "..."
        }
      ],
      "sku": "",
      "price": 67500
    }
  ],
  "tax_lines": [],
  "shipping_lines": [],
  "fee_lines": [],
  "coupon_lines": [
    {
      "id": 1793,
      "code": "10Code",
      "discount": "10000.00",
      "discount_tax": "0",
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 19329,
          "key": "coupon_data",
          "value": {
            "amount": "10000.00",
            "code": "10Code",
            "date_created": "2018-03-12T19:05:11",
            "date_created_gmt": "2018-03-12T15:35:11",
            "date_modified": "2018-03-12T19:15:35",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2018-03-12T15:45:35",
            "description": "",
            "discount_type": "fixed_cart",
            "email_restrictions": [],
            "exclude_sale_items": false,
            "excluded_product_categories": [],
            "excluded_product_ids": [],
            "free_shipping": false,
            "id": 20922,
            "individual_use": true,
            "limit_usage_to_x_items": 0,
            "maximum_amount": "0.00",
            "meta_data": [
              {
                "id": 469119,
                "key": "slide_template",
                "value": "default"
              }
            ],
            "minimum_amount": "0.00",
            "product_categories": [],
            "product_ids": [],
            "usage_count": 1,
            "usage_limit": 0,
            "usage_limit_per_user": 1,
            "used_by": [
              "test@gnail.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "refunds": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://.../wp-json/wc/v2/orders/23136"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://.../wp-json/wc/v2/orders"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

any one has any idea why it act like this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce Orders create not compatible for counting the discount and deduct from the total amount of the order.
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11358

So you have to do it in your own way. I have a solution to customize the create order API for the counting the discount.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 'custom_change_shop_order_response', 10, 3 );
function custom_change_shop_order_response( $response, $object, $request ) {
 $order = wc_get_order( $response->data['id'] );
    $used_coupons = $request->get_param( 'coupon_lines' );
    $coupon_amount = 0;
    if( !empty( $used_coupons ) ):
        foreach ($used_coupons as $coupon ){
            $coupon_id = $coupon['id'];
            $coupon_amount = $coupon['amount'];
        }
    endif;

    $order_coupons = $reponse->data['coupon_lines'];
    if( !empty( $order_coupons ) ) :
        foreach ( $order_coupons as $coupon ) {
            wc_update_order_item_meta( $coupon['id'], 'discount_amount', $coupon['amount'] );
        }
    endif;
  $order_total = get_post_meta( $response->data['id'], '_order_total', true );
    $order_total = $order_total - $coupon_amount;
    update_post_meta( $order->ID, '_order_total', $order_total );
    $response->data['total']  = $order_total;

    return $response;
}
```

Now Place your order as below request.

```
{
  "id": 23136,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "number": "23136",
  "order_key": "wc_order_5aasdad3128608",
  "created_via": "rest-api",
  "version": "3.2.6",
  "status": "pending",
  "currency": "USD",
  "date_created": "2018-03-18T17:14:17",
  "date_created_gmt": "2018-03-18T13:44:17",
  "date_modified": "2018-03-18T17:14:17",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2018-03-18T13:44:17",
  "discount_total": "0",
  "discount_tax": "0",
  "shipping_total": "0",
  "shipping_tax": "0",
  "cart_tax": "0",
  "total": "67500",
  "total_tax": "0",
  "prices_include_tax": false,
  "customer_id": 0,
  "customer_ip_address": "",
  "customer_user_agent": "",
  "customer_note": "",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "...",
    "last_name": "...",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "",
    "email": "...",
    "phone": "..."
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": ""
  },
  "payment_method": "...",
  "payment_method_title": "...",
  "transaction_id": "",
  "date_paid": null,
  "date_paid_gmt": null,
  "date_completed": null,
  "date_completed_gmt": null,
  "cart_hash": "",
  "meta_data": [],
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 1792,
      "name": "...",
      "product_id": 22359,
      "variation_id": 22361,
      "quantity": 1,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "67500",
      "subtotal_tax": "0",
      "total": "67500",
      "total_tax": "0",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 19325,
          "key": "...",
          "value": "..."
        },
        {
          "id": 19326,
          "key": "...",
          "value": "..."
        }
      ],
      "sku": "",
      "price": 67500
    }
  ],
  "tax_lines": [],
  "shipping_lines": [],
  "fee_lines": [],
  "coupon_lines": [
    {
      "id": 1793,
      "code": "10Code",
      "amount": "10000.00",
      "discount_tax": "0",
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 19329,
          "key": "coupon_data",
          "value": {
            "amount": "10000.00",
            "code": "10Code",
            "date_created": "2018-03-12T19:05:11",
            "date_created_gmt": "2018-03-12T15:35:11",
            "date_modified": "2018-03-12T19:15:35",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2018-03-12T15:45:35",
            "description": "",
            "discount_type": "fixed_cart",
            "email_restrictions": [],
            "exclude_sale_items": false,
            "excluded_product_categories": [],
            "excluded_product_ids": [],
            "free_shipping": false,
            "id": 20922,
            "individual_use": true,
            "limit_usage_to_x_items": 0,
            "maximum_amount": "0.00",
            "meta_data": [
              {
                "id": 469119,
                "key": "slide_template",
                "value": "default"
              }
            ],
            "minimum_amount": "0.00",
            "product_categories": [],
            "product_ids": [],
            "usage_count": 1,
            "usage_limit": 0,
            "usage_limit_per_user": 1,
            "used_by": [
              "test@gnail.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "refunds": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://.../wp-json/wc/v2/orders/23136"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://.../wp-json/wc/v2/orders"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update the above code to make it work for `percent` type coupons?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, coupon code shows in woocommerce order detail page but it was not applying as shown in image. [image]

For me after changing from `wp-json/wc/v2/` to `wp-json/wc/v3/` worked. I tried doing manual work for this and after days, i figure it out the solution was so simple.