# coupon_lines doesn't work in woocommerce REST API?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to use coupon_lines to create order with woocommerce rest API but doesn't work, I try the following syntax :

coupon_lines: [  
    [            
 
       code: "coupon", 
       discount: "10" 
    ]
]

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Comment: do you found any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349396/create-an-order-with-coupon-lines-in-woocomerce-rest-api